# How to get precise angle values in Qiskit while using initialize() function to generate arbitrary quantum state?

Tags: qiskit, initialization

Is there any way to get the quantum gate values more precisely in qiskit?

For example, if I want to create 1/√3[|00⟩+|01⟩+|11⟩]. By using initialize() I get the following circuit by using the draw() command.
[image]

However, I would like to know the more precise value of the first argument of R() i.e. 1.23 in R(1.23,pi/2) e.g. it could be 1.228967

Can we generate details files of angles of quantum circuits?

Here is the code for that:

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import Decompose

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
initial_state = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1], dtype=float)
initial_state /= np.linalg.norm(initial_state)
qc.initialize(initial_state)
qc.decompose().decompose().decompose().decompose().draw("mpl")
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the only way to do it, but you can always look at the QASM file. You can do it with `qc.qasm(formatted=True)`, which will show you the underlying QASM code. In your case, it looks like this:

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";
qreg q[2];
ry(3*pi/4) q[0];
ry(1.2309594) q[1];
cx q[1],q[0];
ry(-pi/4) q[0];
cx q[1],q[0];
```

The exact angle for Ry gate is 1.2309594.

Answer (score 1):

you can extract it directly like this, I recommend using transpile to decompose all to ry gate instead, where `draw()` will show decimal place without round it to 3 and keep the pi

```
from qiskit.converters import circuit_to_dag
dag = circuit_to_dag(transpile(qc, basis_gates=['ry','cx']))# where you can modify gate you want
gates_param = []
for node in dag.op_nodes():
    if node.op.name == 'ry': #select the gate's parameter you want to extract
        gates_param.append(node.op.params)
print(gates_param)
```

Answer (score 1):

Qiskit stores `Instruction` parameters in `params` attribute. So, you can access these values as follows:

```
for _instruction in circ.data:
    if len(_instruction[0].params) > 0:
        print('\nInstruction:', _instruction[0].name)
        print('Params:', [str(_param) for _param in _instruction[0].params])
```

Where `circ` is the decomposed circuit.